# SQL query involving a four way join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Attempting to create a 4 way query for an MSSQL exercise. Let me describe the tables as briefly I can:

4 main tables, Vendors (vendor details, pk vendorId), Invoices (invoice details pk InvoiceId,fk VendorID), InvoiceLineItems (I) and GlAccounts(accountNo pk).

Query: *Write a SELECT statement that returns four columns: VendorName, AccountDescription, LineItemCount, and LineItemSum. LineItemCount is the row count, and LineItemSum is the sum of the InvoiceLineItemAmount column*

My solution:

```
SELECT Vendors.VendorName, GLAccounts.AccountDescription, 
  SUM(InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceLineItemAmount) as LineItemSum, 
  Count (InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID) as LineItemCount
FROM Vendors  INNER JOIN Invoices
ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID 
INNER JOIN InvoiceLineItems
  ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID
INNER JOIN GLAccounts
  ON InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo = GLAccounts.AccountNo
ORDER BY  Vendors.VendorName
```

THE ISSUE:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Vendors.VendorName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

THE DILEMMA:

Not sure why this problem is happening because very clearly I mention Vendors.VendorName  in the Group By clause. I suspect it has something to do with the inner joins I am performing since they are multiple, I must have got something wrong.

Can anyone spot what's wrong here?

Comment: If you have multiple line items on an invoice with multiple gl accounts, what should be returned: a comma-delimited list?

Comment: You clearly mention it in *which* `GROUP BY` clause?

Answer (score 2):

Add a GROUP BY Vendors.VendorName, GLAccounts.AccountDescription

Answer (score 2):

Because you are summarizing (aggregating) `InvoiceLineItemAmount` and `InvoiceID` down to one result for each `VendorName`, you also need to do the same for the `VendorName` and `AccountDescription` columns. Just add a

```
GROUP BY Vendors.VendorName, GLAccounts.AccountDescription
```

on the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT Vendors.VendorName, GLAccounts.AccountDescription, SUM(InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceLineItemAmount) as LineItemSum, Count (InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID) as LineItemCount FROM Vendors INNER JOIN Invoices ON Vendors.VendorID = Invoices.VendorID INNER JOIN InvoiceLineItems ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID INNER JOIN GLAccounts ON InvoiceLineItems.AccountNo = GLAccounts.AccountNo Group By Vendors.VendorName, GLAccounts.AccountDescription ORDER BY Vendors.VendorName.
```

`Sum, Count, Avg etc` are aggregate functions, so the records have to be grouped on certain criteria to perform these operations.

Answer (score 0):

We must account for the possibility that you have multiple gl account values on the same invoice. To do that we need to use a subquery which will give us a delimited list of those account numbers. In addition, it is suggested that you are doing this for a single invoice? If so, the result might look like:

```
Select V.VendorName
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + GA1.AccountDescription
        From InvoiceLineItems As LI1
            Join GLAccounts As GA1
                On GA1.AccountNo = LI1.AccountNo
        Where LI1.InvoiceId = I.InvoiceId
        Group By GA1.AccountDescription
        Order By GA1.AccountDescription
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') As AccountDescriptions
    , Coalesce( LineItemInfo.ItemCount, 0 ) As LineItemCount
    , Coalesce( LineItemInfo.AmountTotal, 0 ) As LineItemSum
From Vendors As V
    Join Invoices As I
        On I.vendorid = V.vendorid
    Left Join   (
                Select LI2.InvoiceId
                    , Count(*) As ItemCount
                    , Sum(LI2.Amount) As AmountTotal
                From InvoiceLineItems As LI2
                Group By LI2.InvoiceId
                ) As LineItemInfo
        On LineItemInfo.InvoiceId = I.InvoiceId
Where I.InvoiceId = @SomeInvoiceId
```